# What is good book to start learning about the Seerah of Prophet Muhammad (SAW)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Can anyone suggest me any website/ PDF book/ ebook of The Biography of Our Prophet Muhammad Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam (PUBH)?

I do want to know maximum information about his life, and his sayings. everything and maximum information. Please suggest me if anybody know.

Comment: Questions on book recommendations are not particularly constructive in the Stack Exchange model, and are more likely to attract opinions rather than practical answers; see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/261/22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many books on the [Seerah (biography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirah_Rasul_Allah) of Prophet Muhammad (SAW). Some of them are very thorough and detailed, for example [Sirat-un-Nabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirat-un-Nabi) has five volumes. You can find [a list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biographies_of_Muhammad).

To start, [Ar-Raheeq Al-Makhtum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar-Raheeq_Al-Makhtum) is one of the greatest. This book won the first prize in the first Islamic Conference on Seerah, in 1979. It is originally written in Arabic, but translated in Urdu by the author himself. The revised English version is good too. You can buy it from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W03CVQQ).

If you [click here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Ar-Raheeq%20Al-Makhtum%20PDF), you can find the PDF version.

Answer (score 1):

Sirat Al-Rasul by Ibn Ishaq. I believe it was the only "full" biography penned by a sahabah during his lifetime.

Comment: It is also the earliest surviving text of this kind and the most highly respected. There is an excellent English translation by Professor Guillaume in case you cannot read Arabic.